# How to change values in Column A based on values in Column B and Column A itself?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

How could I write a conditional statement that changes values in column A based on values of column B and column A itself.

A  B ----change to--->  A  B

0  1 -----------------------1  1

Here is what I have tried but it does not seem to work

df.loc[(df[A] == "0") & (df[B] == 1) , A] == 1

Any advice would help. Thanks.

Comment: Please give a minimal example.

Comment: If column A observation equals 0 and column B observation equals 1, change column A observation to 1. @roadrunner66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example should work but this is an alternative.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
              'B':[1,1,1,1,0,1,0]})

filter = (df['A'] == 0) & (df['B'] == 1)

df['A'] = df['A'].where(~filter, 1)
```